# Tracking specific data in string using Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm still new to coding in general, and I'm running into an issue with a Swift exercise.

How do I track the number of times 1 (var numberOfSteps) and the number of times 2 (var numberOfHeartBeats) appears in the string "12221231221"?

I'm given the following hint but not sure how the for-in loop applies:

```
let activityData = "12221231221"
var numberOfSteps = 0
var numberOfHeartBeats = 0

for character in activityData{
 print(character)
}
```

Comment: Educated guess: it loops, from left-to-right, over the characters in the string `activityData`, i.e. each `print` will print out one character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the loop, you can check what the current characters is, then increment the variable accordingly:

```
let activityData = "12221231221"
var numberOfSteps = 0
var numberOfHeartBeats = 0

for character in activityData{
    if character == "1" {
        numberOfSteps += 1
    } else if character == "2" {
        numberOfHeartBeats += 1
    }
}
```

Here is another more functional way of doing this:

```
let dict = Dictionary(grouping: activityData, by: { $0 }).mapValues { $0.count }
```

`dict["1"]` is `numberOfSteps` and `dict["2"]` is `numberOfHeartBeats`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a for loop you can do

```
let activityData = "12221231221"
var numberOfSteps = 0
var numberOfHeartBeats = 0

for character in activityData{
    switch character {
    case "1":
        numberOfSteps += 1
    case "2":
        numberOfHeartBeats += 1
    default:
    break
    }
}

print("Number of steps: \(numberOfSteps), number of hartbeats: \(numberOfHeartBeats)")
```

A more condensed solution without a loop

```
print("Number of steps: \( activityData.filter( {$0 == "1"} ).count), number of hartbeats: \( activityData.filter( {$0 == "2"} ).count)")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in simple way like this:-

```
let occurrencesOne = text.characters.filter { $0 == "1" }.count
let occurrencesTwo = text.characters.filter { $0 == "2" }.count
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use `reduce`, this is kinda equivalent to manually looping over the string, but will less and mode concise code, and without the disadvantage of creating intermediary structures (like arrays of dictionaries), which for large inputs can be problematic memory-wise:

```swift
let activityData = "12221231221"
let numberOfSteps = activityData.reduce(0) { $1 == "1" ? $0 + 1 : $0 }
let numberOfHeartBeats = activityData.reduce(0) { $1 == "2" ? $0 + 1 : $0 }

print(numberOfSteps, numberOfHeartBeats) // 4, 6
```

One step further to reduce the duplication would be to add a function to compute the `reduce` second parameter:

```swift
func countIf<T: Equatable>(_ search: T) -> (Int, T) -> Int {
    return { $1 == search ? $0 + 1 : $0 }
}

let activityData = "12221231221"
let numberOfSteps: Int = activityData.reduce(0, countIf("1"))
let numberOfHeartBeats = activityData.reduce(0, countIf("2"))

print(numberOfSteps, numberOfHeartBeats)
```

Comment: And in Swift 5 there will be `count(where:)` – https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0220-count-where.md

Comment: Or, if you wanted to avoid looping through multiple times, `let frequency = activityData.reduce(into: [Character: Int]()) { $0[$1, default: 0] += 1 }`...

Comment: @Rob that would defeat the purpose of not creating intermediary data structures (yes, `Int` is a structure also, I understand the irony :)

Comment: @MartinR yes, it would be simpler in Swift 5.

Comment: @Rob well, it will always be time over space ;)

Comment: Interesting, @Rob, I wouldn't have expected so much difference between the classic loop and the `reduce`/`count` approaches, since their implementation is basically doing the same iteration. On the other hand we have to compare the loop bodies: one increment vs calling a closure...

Comment: Yeah, there isn’t a material difference in `for` and `reduce` (in optimized builds) but in Sweeper and Jaokim’s `for` loop solutions, they’re looping only once and doing both counts, where as you’re looping twice, and that does make a difference. And the benchmarks prove that out. (Sorry for deleting my previous performance comment as the results were slightly different in Swift 5 (where the `frequency` approach edged ahead of this two `reduce`/`count` approach), so I didn’t want to mislead/confuse anyone, nor drag anyone through the weeds of the results.)

Comment: OK, thanks for the details, @Rob. Even if plainly iterating the array will give the best performance, it will not give the nicest code :). Now, the OP can get an informed opinion on which approach to choose :)